# Create header for http requests

Tags: angular, http

I want to create a header for a http get request which should have following key and value

[image]

Currently I am doing this to achieve it:

```
let header= new Headers();
header.append('Authorization','Token '+this.auth.data.authtoken);
```

But it is 401 unauthorized response. But in postman it is working.

Comment: are you setting options? let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }); then passing this as the third option of the post request

Comment: Look at my get file function and it's responce

Answer (score 2):

you can add headers like

```
 let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Authorization': api_token);

    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http
        .get(url, options);
```

Comment: Have a look at my function and response in answer section

Answer (score 0):

When setting Authorization header. Its pretty standard to have a space 
 between auth token and the prefix.

```
let header= new Headers(); header.append('Authorization','Token ' + ' '+ this.auth.data.authtoken);
```

Also you need to append Content-type header.